# In Autodesk Maya how much do vertices and vertix faces take to render

Tags: rendering, maya

It took me the last 30 minutes to remove vertices inside straight lines and to merge faces which connect at the same angle (additionally to the inbuild "lower polygon-count" function). Now I'm wondering if this process is necessary.

Do I need to minimize the amount of vertices in Maya or is it enough to minimize the amount of vertex faces to achieve an optimal rendering 
performance?
If both is necessary, which gives the bigger boost?

Im looking specifically into applications, where very high performance is necessary (games).

Comment: You should test it. Compare to original. I wouldn't do it. Though this is not a good question or stackoverflow

Comment: that would work I guess. That I didn't think of that before.

Comment: Youre right the maya forums wouldve been more appropriate for this